# Fourier series: Does pointwise convergence and absolute summability imply uniform convergence?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I think I read somewhere that if a Fourier series converges pointwise to some $f$ and if the Fourier coefficients are absolutely summable, then the Fourier series converges uniformly.

But now I am not sure that this is actually true.

**Is this true?**

What I do know is that if the limit function $f$ is continuous and the coefficients are absolutely summable then the convergence is uniform. But does this work with continuity replaced with pointwise convergence? My intuition tells me that this feels wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't this follow from Weierstrass' M-test?

Comment: If $\sum_n |a_n|< \infty$ then $\sum_n a_n e^{2i\pi n x}$ converges uniformly and is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is 1-periodic and $(c_n)$ is the sequence of its Fourier coefficients. Let $S_nf = \sum_{|k|\leq n} c_ke^{2\pi ik\cdot}$ be the $n$th partial sum. Then, $$\sup_x |S_nf(x)-S_mf(x)| \leq \sum_{n<|k|\leq m}|c_n|$$ for $n<m$. Thus, if the Fourier series of $f$ is absolutely summable, then $(S_nf)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, so uniformly convergent.